# leaflet with GitHub URL in package.json

Tags: npm, leaflet

I need an [unreleased upstream fix](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/8288) in `leaflet`.

If I switch `leaflet` to use [GitHub URL](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#github-urls) in my `package.json`:

```json
"leaflet": "github:Leaflet/Leaflet#main",
```

Then I get this error starting my React app:

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/@react-leaflet/core/lib/dom.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'leaflet' in '/workspaces/jefmap/node_modules/@react-leaflet/core/lib'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because because the [main file](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/40c42e7a17f8b4e772ee8b0f4fa3a288431bce47/package.json#L35) for `leaflet` (`dist/leaflet-src.js`) is not checked in to the GitHub repo.

I was able to work around by:

1. Fork the `leaflet` repo
2. Checkout the fork and run `npm run build`
3. [Add the files](https://github.com/JEFuller/Leaflet/commit/9103fcb25e7a81f2a89f12aa5a93411fc80fbf8b) with `git add -f dist/`
4. Change `package.json` to use the fork:

   ```json
   "leaflet": "JEFuller/Leaflet#main",
   ```

---

[Issue on leaflet repo to address this](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/8349).